# Is there a way to have the package explorer show assemblies that have TODOs in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In the tasks view, I can see all of my TODOs.  This is great except for the fact that I've inherited a lot of legacy code that has a lot of TODOs that will never get done.  I think that a project should not be counted as done if there are any TODOs (This is specific for my team, I'm not advocating philosophy here).  So I'd like to see my TODOs without seeing the legacy code's.

Is there a way I can have the package explorer annotate the icons of my projects for TODOs the way it does for warnings and icons?  I can then use this to quickly see which of my projects I need to deal with rather than dig through the task list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom **Task Tag**, and use it instead of the `TODO` tags.

From Preferences search for **Task Tags**, choose the category you are interested in (e.g. **Java** --> **Compiler** --> **Task Tags**) and add a new tag with a name of your choice.

You can then control what to appear on the task list from the Task List's **View Menu** (the arrow on the upper-right of the task list), select **Configure Contents** and add a **New** configuration with the **Description Text** equal to your custom tag name. Select the new configuration and un-select the `TODOs`, and the tasks annotated with the custom tag will appear on the task list.

And you can always add a **Template** for your custom tag for easy access.

Comment: That's a great idea.  The only problem I have with it is that TODO is used throughout the whole team and it would be difficult to convince them to all change their templates to use this custom tag.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to check only the tasks you create. Well, if the legacy tasks are never to be resolved, you may consider deleting them, or better yet, updating **them** to a custom tag and keep using the TODO for the new ones. So, if someday someone wanted to check and resolve these legacy task, it would be possible to look them up.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still interesting for someone:

There is a plug-in called [Task Tag Decorator](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/task-tag-decorator).

The only downside as of today is that it doesn't support the latest Eclipse versions (last support is for 2018-09 (4.9)). Hopefully support for current versions is added soon.